Adjust bones scale along nurbs path
Is it possible to adjust bones auto scaling along nurbs path(spline IK) like follow:


If I get it right, you would like the tail of the 4th bone (from the left) to remain at the same position when bone "Heel 2" is moved ? How many control points are along the curve ? Is there such a control point at the tail of the 4th bone ?

Three control points along the curve, each hooked for bone. I need the tail 4th to remain position hook 1, for this example it is the same position(on picture no Heel, but Hook), but for moving bones with hook 1,  tail 4th bone  follow up control poin 1(with hook 1). So scale for bones 1-4 is one value, scale for bones 5-8 second value (each segment curve have owned scale)

I can not figure out an other way than to split the curve in two objects. Is it fine for you ?

yet I made so, but it not good - for each curve need separate control object, too difficult to make, to control. It`s may manually shaping bones chain by set move/rotate/scale each bone, without any curve.

I have a solution based on Bendy Bones if you are interested...

Thanks, I need some time to learn this variant by google, may be i can to apply for my task

(Using Blender 4.2.3)
Overview
Bendy Bones are an alternative to the Spline IK constraint, with on the one hand a control over the number of subdivisions per bone, and on the other hand a control of the position and tangent direction of spline handles. The full setup is done in Edit Mode and in Pose Mode.

Setup in Edit Mode


1. The path is made of two bones, labeled "Front" and "Back". "Back" is a child of "Front" ; it is created by extrusion. These bones are Deforming the mesh.
2. Handles direction is controlled by not parented bones, labeled "Tangent *". To clarify the view in Edit Mode, these bones are slightly offset in Z direction. They are not Deforming the mesh.
3. "Front" and "Back" bones are subdivided respectively in 4 and 6 Segments ; "Tangent *" bones are made of a single segment.
4. The type of "Front" and "Back" custom Handles is set to Tangent, meaning that "The Bézier handle is controlled by the orientation of the handle bone, independent of its location". "Tangent 0", "Tangent 1" and "Tangent 2" are specified as handle bones.
5. The Ease In/Out property can be adjusted to control the handles length. It is to notice that this value is added to the one specified in Pose Mode.
Setup in Pose Mode


6. To simplify the setup, Copy Location constraints are added to the "Tangent *" bones to move them on the Head/Tail of the bone of which they control the tangent direction.
7. For the demonstration, only the "Back" bone is rotated and scaled. It is to notice that its Location is determined by its parent, the "Front" bone.
8. For the demonstration, only the "Tangent 2" bone is rotated.
9. The Ease In/Out property can be adjusted also in Pose Mode to control the handles length. It is to notice that this value is added to the one specified in Edit Mode.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.3+)

Some problems after exporting to the fbx file.
I added a bone to control by IK,  with rotation and strength(set in 1.0 in bone IK). But after export no any tangent deform, work IK only. Although, IK not correct too, simultaneously rotation and strength.
https://prnt.sc/t_XJXRk6FoxI
is it possible add file in comment?

I recommend to ask this as a new question, because it seems related to FBX export.

I don't think it can be fixed here, just reported. There are other disadvantages compared to spline IK. I`d like to fix spline better.

Problem with scaling spline can be solved by setting Bone Original in Y Scale Mode and manually control it.
Important for spline using and fbx export:
Spline IK bake and export problem
